# Setup IIS to prompt for username/password Window instead of using a form?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, .htaccess

On a linux box using .htaccess you can deny access to folders etc... and when the user attemps to visit that directory/file, a window pops up asking for username/password.

How would you do this on iIS 6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the IIS MMC you could do the following:

- Navigate to a website
- Right click click in a folder
- Choose "Properties"
- Choose "Directory Security" tab
- Click "Edit" under "Authentication and access control"
- Uncheck "Enable anonymous access"
- Check "Basic Authentication"

Then add a local Windows account and add that user to have "Read" access to the directory using normal NTFS permissions.

It will prompt for a password and the Windows Account credentials will let you in.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [IISPassword](http://www.iistools.com/en/iispassword.html) in the past with great success. I believe that this will work with IIS6.

UPDATE: just checked and it does work on IIS6 - no updates since 2009 though...